# Upgrade to 5.47.2 now cron does nothing - how to fix?

Tags: cron

Since upgrading to 5.47.2 cron has stopped doing anything.  It's running as I have redirected the output to a file (which shows zero bytes) but nothing is happening.  The cron user is authorised and the password OK - nothing was changed from previous release. In the course of upgrading I had to restore the database back to 5.45.3 after a failed upgrade - then I upgraded to 5.46.3 and then to 5.47.2 successfully.  All seems OK except for cron. This is a Drupal 7 install, I changed to PHP 7.4 but reverted back to 7.3 after this problem (it didn't help). There are no messages in ConfigandLog. I'm out of ideas on what to do! Suggestions please.

Answer (score 3):

The cause was a folder permissions problem.  The folders at the 2 bottom levels of [www.mysite.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php](http://www.mysite.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php) had got changed from 755 to 777.  When I tried to execute the cron command on another working install as a logged in user (but without the username etc) I got a nice message saying I needed to put the user name etc.  On the problem install I got 'cannot find the page', which led me down that track.  I spent ages on this...  This may have been caused by the upgrade to 5.47.2 crashing. Now back at 5.46.3